# Child Rows and PHP sourced data issues on

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am developing a web application for myself to learn JavaScript/jQuery, and I am trying to use dataTables plug-in for display data on page.

I am failing to implement Child Rows, to detail my data - I get "Uncaught ReferenceError" when tying to expand child row. I found on my searches, solutions for similar problems; but I'm having trouble applying to my code due the way I structured it for get data from a PHP file.
On solution I found, this problem was generated for using different variable names for the table on dataTables settings and click event.

In my case, my dataTables settings is inside a callback function, due to PHP request (It was the way I successfully did it work, after long hours trying - I was having problems with async on JavaScript), therefore I don't have it as a variable to make the reference.

The way I am getting data from PHP it's working, but I am not sure if it is the most appropriate manner.

I am looking for a solution to set the Child Rows without messing up my PHP request. This solution can be either by changing the way data is get from PHP or the way Child Rows is setted.

```
function dataJSON(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "historicoTransacoes.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
    }).done(function (data) {
        callback(data);
    }).fail(function () {
        console.log("Erro na requisição");
    });
};

function dataJSON2(data) {
    d = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(d)

   var table = $('#ultimosLancamentos').dataTable({
        //"bProcessing": true,
        //"serverSide": true,
        data: d,
        paging: true,
        ordering: false,
        info: true,
        columns: [
            {
                "className": 'details-control',
                "orderable": false,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            {data: "local"},
            {data: "tipotransacao"},
            {data: "contain"},
            {data: "contaout"},
            {data: "valor"},
            {data: "datatransacao"}
        ]
    });

}

$('#ultimosLancamentos tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row(tr);

    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    } else {
        // Open this row
        row.child(format(row.data())).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
});


function format(d) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
            '<tr>' +
            '<td>' + d.descricao + '</td>' +
            '</tr>' +
            '</table>';
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    dataJSON(dataJSON2);
    var table = $('#ultimosLancamentos').dataTable;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it work with these changes:

```
            function dataJSON() {
                var d=[];

                $.ajax({
                    url: "historicoTransacoes.php",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "html",
                    async: false,
                    success : function(data) {
                    //console.log(data);
                    d.push(data);
                    }, error : function(req, err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    }
                });

                //console.log(d[0]);
                return JSON.parse(d[0]);
                    };

            function format(d) {
                // `d` is the original data object for the row
                return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
                        '<tr>' +
                        '<td>' + d.descricao + '</td>' +
                        '</tr>' +
                        '</table>';
            }

                d=dataJSON();
                //console.log(d);

            $(document).ready(function () {



                var table = $('#ultimosLancamentos').DataTable({
                    //"bProcessing": true,
                    //"serverSide": true,
                    data: d,
                    paging: true,
                    ordering: false,
                    info: true,
                    columns: [
                        {
                            "className": 'details-control',
                            "orderable": false,
                            "data": null,
                            "defaultContent": ''
                        },
                        {data: "local"},
                        {data: "tipotransacao"},
                        {data: "contain"},
                        {data: "contaout"},
                        {data: "valor"},
                        {data: "datatransacao"}
                    ]
            });

                $('#ultimosLancamentos tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var row = table.row(tr);

                if (row.child.isShown()) {
                    // This row is already open - close it
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                } else {
                    // Open this row
                    row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                }
            });
        });
```

The key was setting ajax async propertie to 'false', so I could pass the Json from request to a JavaScript variable.
Still don't know if it is the most apporpriete way, but it worked.
Any tips for improve this code are still welcome!

Comment: Another hint I would suggest, as long as you're still learning and didn't get used to that approach of retrieving data via AJAX. **NEVER EVER** use that as it will raise all sorts of issues related to async nature of AJAX and will screw performance when you'll need to refresh your table dynamically and start destroying/purging DataTables. Always prefer [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option instead. That'll give you even more flexibility than plain jQuery methods, like `$.ajax()` or `$.get()`.

Comment: Another humble piece of advice: don't cook up table HTML on your own. DataTables can perfectly do that for you, as long as you downloaded the library, you don't need to waste your time, efforts and code lines to reinvent the feature being already around.